# Express/mySQL query not working basic insert

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S6X1.png

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const port = 3001

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "website"
});



app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  console.log(err)
});

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  var insert = "INSERT INTO users (Name, School, Degree) VALUES ('Anthony', 'UARK', 'CSCE')";
  db.query(insert, (err, result) => 
  {
    res.send("Hello")
  })
  
  
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Im just trying to test my connection by adding a row to my table. Any input on how to fix or to help test the problem is appreciated. Ive been folowing along with a youtube video and im not sure where i went wrong the comments section hasnt helped much either. The db name and table name are both correct and so is the password.

Ive added console logs to the app.get and the db.query and they are not showing up in the console but the res.send is showing up on the localhost:port

Comment: make sure code execution is reaching that specific instruction, consider adding some console.log(...) statements in app.get('/', ...) to make sure that db.query(...) statement is getting executed.

Comment: are you getting an error from db? In your code you are ignoring errors that might occurred when insert record to DB, please consider adding `if(err) console.error(err)` to `db.query` callback function

Answer (score -1):

As shown in this NodeJS package [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) documentation you can try this:

```
var mysql      = require("mysql");
var db         = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "website"
});

db.connect(error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("Connected to database.");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    var insert = "INSERT INTO users (Name, School, Degree) VALUES ('Anthony', 'UARK', 'CSCE')";
    db.query(insert, (err, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("Data Inserted.");
        res.send("Data Inserted.");
    });
});
```

Ideally, you want your insert query to be coded as follows:

```
var insert = "INSERT INTO users (Name, School, Degree) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
var dataToInsert = { Name: "Anthony", School: "UARK", Degree: "CSCE" };
db.query(insert, dataToInsert, (err, result) => {
    //...
```

Also, typically database inserts with data are sent to the server via a POST request.